# rails 3 - paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

With paperclip, how can you get paperclip to use full urls like http://mysite.com/image/asdasd.png

versus /image/asdad.png

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are uploading files to amazon S3 then

```
s3.url
```

gives the full image path. But in case of local file storage, you can set :url option also

Answer (score 2):

Once you configure the `:url` interpolation string to your satisfaction, you can link to attachments with the full URL using something like:

```
def attachment_path(attachment)
  attachment.url
end

def attachment_url(attachment)
  "#{root_url}#{attachment.url.gsub(/^\//, '')}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the behavior to work like the _url helpers on the controller/view level, its a little complicated as paperclip functions without the benefit of knowing the host from the request. An easy way to get around this is to define the constant HOST in the config/environments/ENV.rb and then passing the url parameter to has_attachment like

```
:url => "http://#{HOST}/:path"
```

or whatever your url rules are.

You can also side step this issue by using S3, which is kind of a life saver

Comment: make sure you've defined HOST and are using double quotes (it's just normal built in string interpolation)